# Is it possible to use nested class property from model in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have table called `Foo` and helper class called `Bar`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar DateStart { get;set; }
    public Bar DateEnd { get;set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public DateTime Date { get;set; }

    ...and some other properties

    public CreateEventDateTime(DateTime date)
    {
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

In `DbContext` I have conversion from table columns of type `DateTime` to my class `Bar`:

```
builder.Entity<Foo>().Property(f => f.DateStart).HasConversion(
    v => v.Date,
    v => new Bar(v)
);
builder.Entity<Foo>().Property(f => f.DateEnd).HasConversion(
    v => v.Date,
    v => new Bar(v)
);
```

I try to do this select:

```
_applicationDbContext.Foo.Where(f => f.DateStart.Date != f.DateEnd.Date).ToList();
```

And I get error: `System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Foo>
    .Where(f => f.DateStart.Date != f.DateEnd.Date)' could not be translated.`.

But if I set `DateStart` and `DateEnd` as `DateTime` property instead of using class and property in it, LINQ does not have problem. Is there some way to use property from nested class in LINQ?

I just started to learning `.NET` so I do not have much experience. I need to use that class to avoid having duplicit code in my model class.

Using `ASP .NET Core 3.1`

Comment: Usually a database is a flat table like a worksheet.  Nesting is usually achieved by having a column in the table be a parent/child so you can get nesting.

Comment: I know. Maybe I used wrong title but hope my problem is explained enough. I just trying to convert table column into custom class and use it in query.